# NestJS + Jest: how to receive external http requests within integration test?

Tags: jestjs, controller, nestjs, integration-testing, code-coverage

## Goal

In my setup I have two applications. Application A (from a third party ) receives user input, processes it and then sends the processed data via POST to Application B (my nestjs server). I want to run an integration test, where I want to validate internal variables of Application B against User input.  For this I want to define the tests within B which do the following steps:

- send predefined user input to A
- receive a POST from A
- do some processing
- validate the processing

Defining the tests within B should give the possibility to examine code coverage for the integration tests. I can't do this if I write another application which tests from external.

## Problem

I didn't find any way how to receive external http requests within jest tests. My approach would be to create a module with a controller and then listen to the port. For example like this

```js
describe('Integration Test', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const testingModule: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule(
            {
                imports: [HttpModule],
                providers: [IntegrationTestService],
                controllers: [IntegrationTestController],
            },
        ).compile();

        await testingModule.listen(3000);
        // here I define my tests
    });
}
```

But TestingModule doesn't provide the function "listen". I also didn't get it working using a predefined normal module that is created via `NestFactory.create(IntegrationTestModule)`.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: What about doing [`const app = testingModule.createNestApplicaiton(); await app.listen(3000)`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Thanks for your suggestion! I got another unrelated error but when I resolved it it finally worked. If you want to repost your suggestion I will approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the test server on a port, you need to call `testingModule.createNestApplication()` [like it shows in the docs under e2e tests](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing). Adding this to the end of your `beforeAll()` will allow you to receive the http requests

```js
const app = testingModule.createNestApplicaiton();
await app.listen(3000);
```